# dropdown list from text input

Tags: javascript, html

I do not even know how to begin that is why I am not adding code. But I need to create a dropdown name with names the user has entered before, and I know how to make a dropdown list but I do not know how to make the names the user enteres as elements in the dropdown. Thank You

Comment: To start of you need to get user input in an edit text and then pass it to the dropdown adapter

Answer (score 0):

if you store the names in an array you could try something like

```js
let dropdown = document.querySelector('select')
let names = ['john', 'alex', 'alissa', 'sam']

names.forEach(name => {
  let option = document.createElement('option')
  option.value = name
  option.innerText = name
  dropdown.append(option)
})
```

```html
<select></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a text `input` a `button` and `select`. On click of the button trigger a function which will take the value from the input.Create an array which will store all the text input. If the array already contains the value entered through text input , then dont add it again.Else call the function to take text input and remove white space. Then call another function which will loo through this array and during each iteration it will create a `option` using `document.createElement` and will append itself to the select.

```js
let optionArray = [];

function addToOption() {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById("userName").value.trim();
  if (optionArray.indexOf(inputValue) === -1) {
    optionArray.push(inputValue)
  }
  addToSelect();
}

function addToSelect() {
  if (optionArray.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const selectBox = document.getElementById('selectOption');
  selectBox.innerHTML = '';
  optionArray.forEach((item) => {
    const elem = document.createElement('option');
    const optionText = document.createTextNode(item);
    elem.appendChild(optionText);
    elem.id = optionText;
    selectBox.appendChild(elem)
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userName">
<button type="button" onClick="addToOption()">Add</button>
<select id="selectOption"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Jquery code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update list item</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
      </script>
    
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" name="listitem" id="content">
    <button id="updateBtn">Add to list</button>
    <hr>
    <select id="listelement">
        <option>test option</option>
    </select>
        

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#updateBtn").click(function(){
                var content=$("#content").val();
                var listitem='<option>'+content+'</option>';
                $("#listelement").append(listitem); 
        });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```